# htaccess and htpasswd trouble

Tags: htaccess, apache2, authentication, htpasswd

This is the first time that I have ever tried working with .htpasswd and .htaccess files, so please point out my childish works.

I have my apache document root set to `/www/` on my debian server. Inside it, there's a folder named `Logs/` which I want to restrict access using a htpasswd. I created my htpasswd file using the shell's htpasswd command. And this is the result:

```
user:<encoded password here>
hjp:<encoded password here>
hjpotter92:<encoded password here>
```

I put this file named `.htaccess` inside `/www/`. The `Logs/` has following htaccess file in it:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

This was again created using an online tool(I forgot its name/link, and can't search the browser-history now).

The problem, as it might've already struck you is that I am experiencing no change on my Logs folder access. The folder is still accessible to everyone. I am running apache as root user(if that matters/helps). Please help/guide me. I've tried reading some htaccess guides and have followed some of older SO questions, but still haven't figured out a way to restrict access to Logs folder with a password.

Comment: FYI, it should be `.htaccess`, and you should: 1.) not run apache as root (terrible for security), and 2.) use digest authentication unless you're only accessing that URL via HTTPS. Because even if your `.htpasswd` file is SHA1 encrypted, the browser will be sending the password in plain-text if you use basic authentication.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I am fully aware about running apache as root, but since the network is quite private(not more than 300 users, all of whom I know) so, its fine. I am using MD5 instead of SHA1 in .htpasswd .

Comment: Whats the point in storing the passwords in MD5 SHA1 at all if your Apache is running on root. Surely your not worried about security then and hashing the passwords is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem with the help of a person i know. :)

Added this segment to httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /www/ChatLogs>
  Allow from all
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /www/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Because there's a line in `httpd.conf` as follows:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got your problem solved by putting the contents of your .htaccess file into httpd.conf.

Another solution would have been to change the line in your httpd.conf from

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```