# File access forbidden in htpasswd

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I have been using the htpasswd generated in [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28032/14414) and it seemed to have been working well until recently.

Since yesterday, I am not able to access the newest file created in the folder **`ChatLogs`**(named `10_07_2012.txt`). The server returns a **403 Forbidden** error saying:

> ### Forbidden
>
> > You don't have permission to access /ChatLogs/2012/07/10_07_2012.txt on this server.

I am still able to access older files(until `09 July, 2012`). At first I thought it might be because of file permissions, but they are the same as on other 9 files in the folder.

What could be the problem? Please Help.

### EDIT

As per [w3d](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/w3d)'s suggestion, I completely removed my **htpasswd** and **htaccess** files. Restarted the apache2 server(using `service apache2 restart`) and I'm still getting the same **403 Forbidden** error for all chatlogs created after `2012-07-10 00:00:00`.

The chatlog files are created/modified using **[Lua](http://www.lua.org/)** and **[PtokaX](http://www.ptokax.org/)**. The chatlogging script is similar to [this one](http://script-bot.dcstuff.nl/scripts/PtokaX/lua-5-api-1/Chat_History_1.03_L5.1.lua)

Comment: Are you saying that new files in the _same folder_ as older (accessible) files are not accessible? In which case I don't see how it can be a .htpasswd issue, as this would affect the entire folder? Are the file _owners_ the same?

Comment: @w3d Yes, the files are in the same folder. And yes, the file owner is `root` for the files as well as folders. I am able to access `09_07_2012.txt` in the same folder.

Comment: Have you tried removing the password protection altogether, to see if that is indeed the problem? Delete caches, try another browser...? What are the file permissions?

Comment: @w3d OK, restarted **apache2** after removing the htpasswd file. And I am still unable to access files created/modified after _09th July_.

Comment: And... have you deleted caches, tried another browser, and what are the file permissions? Presumably you are attempting to access these files directly over HTTP? Are you able to access and download these files successfully over FTP? Is the content of these files as expected - no corruption? I'm not familiar with the scripting languages you mention unfortunately, but in the script you link to I cannot see how file permissions are specifically set on the written file, which presumably they would need to be if the script is running as _root_ but the resulting file should be readable by everyone?

Comment: Also... do you have any security modules installed on the server (mod_security perhaps?) which can sometimes result in unexpected bahaviour?!

Comment: w3d suggests lots of possibilities, it is unclear which one would help.